# iOS - TableView - Get Index of Header section on tapping button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have implemented custom header section for UITableView. 
There is a button into the customised view of Header and I want to get the index of that section on tapping action of that button.

I may try by going as

```
CustomHeader *view = (CustomHeader*)btnObject.superView;
```

But from this headerView's Instance how can i get the IndexPath or index of that Section?

**EDIT:**
I need something that is independent on tag or any thing just similar to the indexpath for Cell as below

```
-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathFromSenderView:(UIView*)view{

    CGPoint center= view.center;
    CGPoint rootViewPoint = [view.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.tblMainContainer];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblMainContainer indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: You can assign a tag to the custom header view and fetch that when button is pressed.

Comment: No but what if somehow we delete that section ? then there will be inconsistency.

Comment: On reloading the table `viewForHeaderInSection:` will get called again and hence the tags will be reassigned. So it should work if you reload the table after deleting the section.

Comment: If the tags (standard `int` or custom `id`) don't suit you, there's always an option not to use headers but to have an additional cell when needed, then you can use your `indexPathFromSenderView:`.

Comment: Yes Yogi i agree with you, but what if the Table have around 10-15 rows with Images and may be some bulky content? so is it appropriate to reload whole table just to reassign tags and remove a single row ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    // create custom header here

    // set up a button method
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // set the button tag as section
    yourButton.tag = section;

    return yourCustomHeaderWithButton;
}


later


-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender{

    UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"section : %i",clickedButton.tag);

}
```

Comment: But if the section is going to be deleted then it will create crash.

Comment: No. first test it and let me know. it will work even though deleted rows. Once deleted the rows reload the data by reloaddata method call. that's it

Comment: I was doing samething but it crashed.because on deleteing perticular section it never updates other sections tag, its very obvious

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the tag. There's no way to get the indexPath from a header section unlike a normal cell. If you want, you can make the header section view into a UITableViewCell row instead and just add it as the top row in your section.

BTW you can use

```
[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]
```

instead to get the index path for a cell.

If you decide to use a tag, you can update the tag value by using the following code in your action method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

This will prevent the tag value from being wrong and stop your application from crashing.